# How to force an order of Spring Security HTTP filters?

Tags: java, spring-security

I have "main" Spring Security filter added in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter .configure` method:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
// omitted for brevity....
http.apply(new JwtTokenFilterConfigurer(jwtTokenUtil, objectMapper));
}

}
```

and the `SecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
public class JwtTokenFilterConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {

// omitted for brevity....

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    final JwtTokenFilter customFilter = new JwtTokenFilter(jwtTokenUtil, objectMapper);
    http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

  }

}
```

There is another HTTP filter(s), eg:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 2)
public class WhitelistOriginatedFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
// omitted for brevity....
}
```

Filtering works as expected but this filter is executed **before** `JwtTokenFilter` defined in `JwtTokenFilterConfigurer`.

---

**Question:** Is there way how to force that `JwtTokenFilter` will be executed before all other HTTP filters without need to do not specify `@Order` in these other filters? (because I need to set the execution order of these filters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by implementing the `SecurityConfigurerAdapter` and setting the filters in the desired order.

```
public class HttpFilterConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {

  private final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
  private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  public HttpFilterConfigurer(final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil, final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {

    AssertUtils.notNull(jwtTokenUtil, "jwtTokenUtil");
    AssertUtils.notNull(objectMapper, "objectMapper");

    this.jwtTokenUtil = jwtTokenUtil;
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    final CopyRequestBodyHttpFilter copyRequestBodyFilter = new CopyRequestBodyHttpFilter();
    http.addFilterBefore(copyRequestBodyFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    final CorrelationIdLoggingHttpFilter correlationIdLoggingFilter = new CorrelationIdLoggingHttpFilter();
    http.addFilterAfter(correlationIdLoggingFilter, CopyRequestBodyHttpFilter.class);

    final JwtTokenHttpFilter customFilter = new JwtTokenHttpFilter(jwtTokenUtil, objectMapper);
    http.addFilterAfter(customFilter, CorrelationIdLoggingHttpFilter.class);

    final WhitelistOriginHttpFilter whitelistOriginFilter = new WhitelistOriginHttpFilter(objectMapper);
    http.addFilterAfter(whitelistOriginFilter, JwtTokenHttpFilter.class);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Set a breakpoint in `FilterChainProxy#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse)`, debug and find out the first filter which is actually executed.

Then adjust

```
http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

to

```
http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, <class of the first executed filter>);
```